# How can I create a react and koa project from scract?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

> Hi, I'm new to this react and koa. Is this code correct? I'm trying to create react and koa projects from scratch. I have a react project. I would like to create a downloadable windows exe. I can do it with a node server using Zeit pkg but I don't know how to do that (or something similar) with react.

I have tried Zeit pkg. Not seeing many other options.

**Backend**

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Koa = require('koa');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
const { dbConnect } = require('./utills/dbConnect.js');

const app = new Koa();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser());


//routers
const userRouter = require('./routes/user.router.js');
app.use(userRouter.routes())
    .use(userRouter.allowedMethods());

const vehicleRouter = require('./routes/vehicle.router.js');
app.use(vehicleRouter.routes()) 
    .use(userRouter.allowedMethods());


app.listen(8080, () => {
    dbConnect();
    console.log("Application running on port 8080");
});


//Installed packages
// @koa/cors
// @koa/router
// dotenv
// jsonwebtoken
// koa
// koa-bodyparser
// mongoose
// nodemon
```

**model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    id: {type:String, required:true},
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    email: {type:String, required:true},
    password:{type:String, required:true}
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**Controller**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require("../models/user.model");


const getAllUsers = async (ctx)=>{
    
    await User.find().then((users)=>{
        ctx.body = users;
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })

}

const addUser = async (ctx)=>{
    
    const {id, name, email, password} = ctx.request.body;
    const newUser = new User({id, name, email, password});
    const user = await User.create(newUser);

    if(user){
        ctx.body = user;
        ctx.set('Content-Type', 'application.json');
        ctx.status = 201;
    } else {
        ctx.body = {status:"error occured"}
        ctx.set('Content-Type', 'application.json');
    }
}


const updateUser = async (ctx)=>{
    
    const uid = ctx.params.id;
    const {id, name, email, password} = ctx.request.body;

    const updateUser = {id, name, email, password}

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(uid, updateUser).then(()=>{
        ctx.body = {status:"User Updated"};
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        ctx.body = {status:"Error occured"}
    })
   
}


const deleteUser = async (ctx)=>{
    
    const uid = ctx.params.id;

    await User.findByIdAndDelete(uid).then(()=>{
        ctx.body = {status:"User Deleted"};
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        ctx.body = {status:"Error occured"}
    })
   
}


const login = async (ctx)=>{
    
    const {email, password} = ctx.request.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({email});

    console.log(user)

    if(user && (password == user.password)){
        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            },
            'SecretKey123'
        )

        return ctx.body = {token:token}
    } else {
        return ctx.body = {status:'Login Failed'}
    }
   
}

const auth = async (req, res)=>{
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token']
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123')
        const _id = decoded._id
        const user = await User.findById(_id);

        return res.json({ status: 'ok', name: user.name, role: user.role, id: user._id, subRole: user.subRole, uid:user.id, user:user })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'invalid token' })
    }
}


module.exports = {addUser, updateUser, deleteUser, getAllUsers, login, auth}
```

**Router**

```
 const Router = require('@koa/router');
const { addUser, getAllUsers, updateUser, deleteUser, login, auth } = require('../controller/user.controller');

const userRouter = new Router({
    prefix: '/users'
});

userRouter.get('/',getAllUsers);
userRouter.post('/add',addUser);
userRouter.put('/update/:id', updateUser);
userRouter.delete('/delete', deleteUser);
userRouter.post('/login', login);
userRouter.post('auth', auth)


module.exports = userRouter;
```

**DB Connect**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dbConnect = () => {
    const dbConStr = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

    mongoose.connect(dbConStr, (connection)=>{
        console.log("MongoDB Connection Success");
    })
}

module.exports = {dbConnect}
```

**Frontend**

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Users from './pages/Users';
import Login from './pages/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    div className='container'>
        HeaderComponent/>
        Router>
            Routes>
                Route exact path="/" element={Users/>}/>
                Route exact path="/register" element={Register/>}/>
                Route exact path="/login" element={Login/>}/>
            /Routes>
        /Router>
    /div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Login.jsx**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react";

function Login() {

    //User Details
    const[email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const[password, setPassword] = useState('');

    function loginUserHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = { email, password }

        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/users/login', user).then((res)=>{
            if(res.data.token){
                sessionStorage.setItem("isLogged", true);
                window.location="/";

            } else {
                window.location.reload(false)
                alert("login failed")
            }

        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    return ( 
        div>
            h2 className="text-center mt-3">Login/h2>
            div>
                form style={{width:"50%", margin:"auto"}}>
                    div className="form-group">
                        label>Email : /label>
                        input type="email" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                    /div>

                    div className="form-group">
                        label>Password : /label>
                        input type="password" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                    /div>
                    div className="text-center mt-2">
                        button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={loginUserHandler}>Login/button>
                    /div>
                /form>
            /div>
        /div>
     );
}

export default Login;
```

**Register.jsx**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react";


function Register() {

    //User Details
    const[name, setName] = useState('');
    const[email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const[id, setId] = useState('');
    const[password, setPassword] = useState('');

    function registerUserHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = {name, email, password, id}

        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/users/add', user).then(()=>{
            alert('User added');
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    return (  
        div>
            h2 className="text-center mt-3">Register/h2>
            div>
                form style={{width:"50%", margin:"auto"}}>
                    div className="form-group">
                        label>Name : /label>
                        input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} />
                    /div>
                    div className="form-group">
                        label>Email : /label>
                        input type="email" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                    /div>
                    div className="form-group">
                        label>ID : /label>
                        input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>setId(e.target.value)} />
                    /div>
                    div className="form-group">
                        label>Password : /label>
                        input type="password" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                    /div>
                    div className="text-center mt-2">
                        button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={registerUserHandler}>Register/button>
                    /div>
                /form>
            /div>
        /div>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: … and please also be more specific what the problem is or what specific question you have. Thank you.